AC Stark shift in the non-perturbative regime
I am trying to simulate the following situation. I have a 2 level system, with the energy spacing $\omega_0$. I have a laser, with Rabi frequency $\Omega_1$ and frequency $\omega_1$, which I can scan in order to find the value of the transition frequency, so $\omega_1$ is close in value to $\omega_0$. Then I have a second laser with $\Omega_2$ and $\omega_2$, such that $\omega_2$ is far detuned from $\omega_0$ (but I can still assume $|\omega_2-\omega_1|\ll|\omega_2+\omega_1|$ such that I can apply the RWA). Thus my Hamiltonian is:
$\begin{pmatrix}
0 & \Omega_1\cos{(\omega_1 t)} + \Omega_2\cos{(\omega_2 t)}\\
\Omega_1\cos{(\omega_1 t)} + \Omega_2\cos{(\omega_2 t)} & \omega_0
\end{pmatrix}$
If I now go to the frame rotating with $\omega_0$ and apply the RWA approximation, I end up with the Hamiltonian:
$\begin{pmatrix}
0 & \Omega_1/2 + \Omega_2/2e^{-i\Delta_2}\\
\Omega_1/2 + \Omega_2/2e^{i\Delta_2} & \Delta_0
\end{pmatrix}$
with $\Delta_0 = \omega_0-\omega_1$ and $\Delta_2 = \omega_2-\omega_1$. Now what I would like to do is to calculate the population transfer from one state to the other for a fixed interaction time, for different values of $\omega_1$ i.e. for different values of $\Delta_0$ and $\Delta_2$. So what I tried to do is to simply integrate numerically the SE using this Hamitlonian from $0$ to the time I want, for each value of $\Delta_0$ ($\Delta_2$). However, I am not getting what I would expect. For example, if I choose $\Omega_1 = 1,000$ Hz, $\Omega_2 = 50$ Hz and $\omega_2-\omega_0 = 10,000$ Hz and increase $\omega_1$ (and hence simultaneously $\Delta_0$ and $\Delta_2$ by $25$ Hz) I am getting the first figure below. The transition frequency appears to be shifted by about $60$ Hz. But in this regime, I would expect a shift of about $\frac{\Omega_2^2}{2(\omega_2-\omega_0)} = 0.125$ Hz. Moreover, if I run the same code but choose steps of $5$ Hz instead of $25$ Hz, I am getting the second figure below. I have no idea what is happening? Am I missunderstanding the physics behind what I want to simulate? All I want is to explore how the transition frequency changes (e.g. by measuring the absorption of the $\omega_1$ laser) as a function of the parameters of the second laser. Thank you!


